# Get Name with initial from full name using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I hope to get the name with the initial from the client's full name using the SQL server.
The format should be the First letter of the first name and middle names except last name + Last name

Eg:
If the full name is John Cena, then the output should be J Cena

if the full name is Wathsala Malshani Perera, then the output should be W M Perera.

please help me to build a query.
Thank you

Comment: And what if it's John Cena Snr? or Mr John Cena

Comment: What about other names, like Malcolm McDowell, Conan O'Brien, Carl van der Walt and Jonathan Rhys-Davies?

Comment: @jarlh M McDowell ,  C  O'Brien , C V D Walt , J Rhys-Davies

Comment: This is [loosely possible](https://dbfiddle.uk/bseW1fUA), but there are cases that it won't work for. This is probably worth a read: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LEFT(FirstName, 1), LastName FROM Table
```

Left(column, 1) will return only the first letter for a column. If you have a middle name it should go like this

```
SELECT LEFT(FirstName, 1), LEFT(MiddleName, 1), LastName FROM Table
```

You could also use SUBSTRING(FirstName, 1, 1), which is equivalent to the usage of Left I've shown

Comment: I have only one column in my table called full name.no separate columns for first name, middle name and last name

Comment: You can avoid getting answers that don't meet your requirements by adding sample data and expected outcome to your question.

Comment: *I have only one column in my table* and this is your root issue, store atomic data in its own column. That's today's lesson.

Comment: @delmawax well you could play with variables and give one variable the first letter of the value and the other variable you could give the value after the ' '(spacebar) but it's too much work. It would be much easier to just rework your table

Answer (score 0):

Hello I'm checking your request, and I think the best way should be you to use a stored procedure, I will not address this topic in this answer, but I leave an example algorithm to insert in the store procedure

```
DECLARE @name as nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @nSpace as int
DECLARE @i as int
DECLARE @nameResult as nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @index as int
DECLARE @newname as nvarchar(50)
--you can replace the name for test if all works well
--that variable @name you need to pass in store procedure
SET @name = 'John Cena'
--get the number of the spaces in the string
SET @nSpace = LEN(@name)-LEN(REPLACE(@name, ' ', ''))
--check if the number the spaces is even or odd, if is even need add a space at the end
if @nSpace % 2 = 0 
    SET @name = @name + ' '

--SELECT @nSpace
--index used in the loop
SET @i = 1
--inicialization the variable nameresult
SET @nameResult = ''

while @i <= @nSpace
begin
    --get the index of the position of the space
    SET @index = CHARINDEX(' ',@name)
    --get the first letter of the substring
    SET @newname = SUBSTRING(@name,1,@index)
    --start to mount the name
    SET @nameResult = @nameResult + LEFT(@newname,1) + ' '
    --remove from the name the part already usend
    SET @name = RIGHT(@name,len(@name)-(@index-1))
    --increase the loop
    SET @i = @i + 1

end
--finish with the last name
SET @nameResult = @nameResult + @name
--show the result, in the store procedure that should be the return of the function
SELECT @nameResult
```

Best Regards